# React Flux - Return value from flux dispatcher / store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dependencies, promise, flux

I am using the [flux-pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) and the [flux dispatcher](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html). I need to return a value from 'TextStore' to an action after creating a new TextItem because I need to reference it in another store.
Here is a very simple version of what I want to do:

```
// stores.ts
var TextStore = {
    add(){
        // here I want to return a new ID
        return createRandomID();
    }
    ...
}
var ModuleStore = {
    labelTextID; // refers to `id` on Text
    ...
}


// moduleactions.ts
...
import PageActions from './PageActions';
var ModuleActions = {
    add: function (module) {
        var textID = PageActions.add(); // here I need to get the ID of the newly create `Text`
        module.labelTextID = textID;
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            action: 'ADD_MODULE',
            module: module
        })
    },
    ...
}
```

Now when I add a new `Module` via dispatching an action, I want to create a new `Text` as well and return its newly created ID from the store before.

The most obvious way would be to require the `TextStore` inside `ModuleActions` and call `add()` directly. Is that against the flux-pattern?

Is there any way to accomplish that, maybe with promises? Sending callbacks via the dispatcher to the store doesnt work, because I cannot dispatch while another dispatch is unfinished.

Would be great if you guys can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the Store's method directly is an anti-pattern for Flux. If you directly call `TextStore.add()` then you are not following the

`Action -> Dispatcher -> Store --> View --> Action` cycle.

**In flux, the data should always generate in the `action`**. This makes more sense when the process of generation of data is aync. In your case you were able to get around this because generation of data is not async. You are directly generating the data in the TextStore and then worrying about how to return that value.

In your case generate the `id` in the action as you would have done if it was an async backend event, then pass that `id` down to the `TextStore` via dispatcher and after that also pass the same id to the `ModuleStore` via the dispatcher.

```
var ModuleActions = {
    add: function (module) {
        var textID = new Date().getTime(); // this is the CHANGE i added
        PageActions.add(textID); 
        module.labelTextID = textID;
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            action: 'ADD_MODULE',
            module: module
        })
    }
}
```

You could also break this down into further smaller, more specific actions. I kept it as-is so I could highlight the one line you should change.

Comment: Thanks! I already implemented somewhat similiar, I added a function "getNewId()" inside the store, which I call inside the action.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it going. My two cents would be to generate the data outside the store and pass it in via an action's payload, rather than generating the data inside the store.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to accomplish that, maybe with promises? Sending callbacks via the dispatcher to the store doesnt work, because I cannot dispatch while another dispatch is unfinished.

You can have your async call `PageActions.add();` before you dispatch the `ModuleActions.add` and pass the returned value as a parameter to `ModuleActions.add`

Comment: But there I have the same problem, that I cannot return the ID, because `PageActions.add()` uses the Dispatcher as well. I would have to call `PageStore.add()`, but I think using stores in actions is against the flux-pattern